# UITableView - move cell - How to enter dragging mode without long press?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, long-press

I am using the standard UITableView editingMode to move Cells via Drag & Drop. Works like a charm, perfectly integrated to my Core Data Model and everything.

**However, usability-wise I dislike that the user has to long-press the Editing Accessory (|||). I would like to change the minimum duration of the UILongPressGestureRecognizer to something like 0.1f.**

The trouble: I cant seem to access the right Gesture Recognizer. UITableViewCell's gestureRecognizers-array is empty, the UITableView's gestureRecognizers array contains only private recognizers:

UIScrollViewDelayedTouchesBeganGestureRecognizer
UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer
UISwipeGestureRecognizer
UIGobblerGestureRecognizer

I looked at several github-Projects:
https://github.com/bvogelzang/BVReorderTableView
https://github.com/FlorianMielke/FMMoveTableView https://github.com/mystcolor/JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo https://github.com/shusta/ReorderingTableViewController

They all focus on re-engineering UITableView so you dont have to access the built in editing mode - and instead can long press any UITableViewCell anywhere WITHOUT entering editing mode.

As **I simply want to change the minimumPressDuration of the built in editing mode** (and am actually fine with restricting the "access point" for the drag gesture to the Accessory View) I am reluctant to use these custom implementations potentially prone to errors and trouble.

Looking forward to your help! Thank you!!

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: if you don't long press how is the view going to discern between scrolling and dragging and dropping? If you just start to drag from a cell right away the gesture is exactly like scrolling.. or do all your cells fit in the table view frame so you don't need scrolling?

Comment: Good question, here are my thoughts:
- Scroll whenever the Cells are touched outside of the Drag-Handle-Accessory-View (|||)

- Move cell whenever the Drag-Handler-Accessory-View (|||) is touched

Comment: Did you ever find a way of changing the minimum press duration?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to access the `UITableViewReorderControl`, as discussed in [this article](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point/), and then look for any attached gesture recognizers. If you find any, you should then be able to change the `minimumPressDuration` property.

Comment: I tried this. For some reason the reorder control does not seem to have any gesture recognizers attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 5

You can change the `minimumPressDuration` to 0. So that you can enter drag and drop mode without a long press.

```
let gesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
gesture.minimumPressDuration = 0
```